# Regex indentifier expected error

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I get indentifier expected error with my code. Why?

Code:

```
    Dim inStream As StreamReader
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest
    Dim webresponse As WebResponse
    webRequest = webRequest.Create("https://website.com/search?q=" + kicsereles + "&type=page&0&something=" + tokentext.Text)
    webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
    inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
    RichTextBox2.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd()
    For Each m As Match In New Regex("/:\s+"([\w\s.]+)"/g").Matches(RichTextBox2.Text)
        ListBox6.Items.Add(m.Value)
    Next
```

My regex code: `/:\s+"([\w\s.]+)"/g`

It's look good in http://regex101.com/
But I get error in VB.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have to escape quotes? `"/:\s+\"([\w\s.]+)\"/g"`

Comment: indentifier expected error as well.

Comment: please add the error details to your question

Comment: no error details...incorrect regex for some reason.

Comment: I try something like this: name.:\s+.([\w\s.]+)./g  but it's does't working...

Comment: I think my problem is quotation mark..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- You need to escape the quotes. In VB, you do this by doubling the quote character:

  ```
  New Regex("/:\s+""([\w\s.]+)""/g")
  ```

  But this is still incorrect.
- In the .NET `Regex` class, you don't specify the regex options like in PHP. You have a separate enumeration. And the `g` modifier is not required (it's the API usage that determines if you want all matches or only the first one). This is the correct call:

  ```
  New Regex(":\s+""([\w\s.]+)""")
  ```
- I also believe you want to do only extract the value between quotes:

  ```
  ListBox6.Items.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
  ```
- Oh and please rename your controls, `ListBox6` is a really bad name.
- You should close your streams:

  ```
  Using inStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
      RichTextBox2.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd()
  End Using
  ```